# Gitlab says there are merge conflicts, but actually there are none

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I created a branch from the master. Made four commits to the branch. After the third commit I created a merge request. Till the third commit, Gitlab never complained about merge conflict. On the fourth commit, it suddenly complained about merge conflict. There have been no changes in the master.

[image]

```
$ git branch
  master
* mylocalbranch

$ git rebase master
  Current branch mylocalbranch is up to date.
    
$ git merge master
  Already up to date.

$ git mergetool
  No files need merging
```

[image]

My merge request is fully approved. I have write access to the repository. The Merge button is greyed out. I am not sure how do I resolve the conflicts that Gitlab is complaining about. Not sure how do I get my code to master.

Comment: `git rebase master` won't tell you anything if your local `master` hasn't been pulled from upstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on branch `mylocalbranch` and you are trying to `rebase` your local branch on top of master. Well, it already is on top of master, it already is ahead of it and since there are no new commits in the `master` branch, there is nothing to rebase. Then you are trying to merge `master` into your local branch, but you are already at the latest changes.

You **have to** `pull` master locally and check if there are any changes in that branch. Once you've pulled master, you have to `rebase` and would be able to see the conflicts GitLab is talking about. Fix the conflicts and then push again your local branch.

Comment: Are you suggesting `git checkout master` followed by `git pull --rebase origin master`?

Comment: That is one way to get your remote `master` changes, yes. Also, a check you can do is look at the GitLab UI and see if master on GitLab has one or more commits that you **don't have** locally. That way you can prove that you need to pull master changes from remote.

Comment: There have been no changes to the master since I created the branch in remote or cloned the branch at local.

Comment: What was the result of you `pull`-ing?

Comment: My bad. It pulled one file change. So now that my local master is up to date I issued `git checkout mylocalbranch` followed by `git pull --rebase origin master` to make `mylocalbranch` up to date with master. Were these the right commands?

Comment: You mean `git checkout master` and then `git pull --rebase master`? If you did that, then just rebase `mylocalbranch` like so `git checkout mylocalbranch && git rebase master` and you would see conflicts.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `git fetch origin` followed by `git rebase origin/master`. There's no need to `git checkout master` and `git pull` and `git checkout mybranch`. In fact, you can simply *delete* the `master` branch if you like; you don't need it when `origin/master` will serve (and auto-update). I don't normally bother deleting `master`, but during development, don't normally refer to it either.

Answer (score 1):

> There have been no changes in the master.

Yes, there have.

Remember, Git does not sync to the remote automatically. There have been changes on the remote. But you will not see them on your machine until you fetch.

Answer (score 1):

In a situation where GitLab says there are merge conflict when there are none, I merged the branch locally, and push it. After that, the MR in GitLab was marked as merged.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --no-ff 10-mybranch
$ git push
```

I followed GitLab commit message structure, assuming the branch solves issue number 10 and the MR is number 8.

```
Merge branch '10-mybranch' into 'master'

My extraordinary code is stuffed with bugs.

Closes #10
    
See merge request !8
```